# Google Map not populating div correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map which is supposed to get the users location, centre on the their location and then provide directions to a fixed point on the map.

The problem is that the map is not populating the entire `div` nor is it centering or zooming to the right location it is however loading the users location and giving directions fine. If I recreate it in a jsFiddle though it works fine but when included in my site the problem described arises.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wXnjt/1/

How it looks when included in my site.
[image: Map Bug]

What is causing this problem? (Let me know if you want my code posted in here rather than having to go to the fiddle)

EDIT: There is also no errors appearing in the dev console. I have also tried using `preserveViewport: true` but it had no effect.

Comment: try: google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

Comment: I tried adding that to where the page is loaded on click of a link but it only made the map resize to about 3/4 of the div and it still was not centred or zoomed to the correct location. Did I place it in the wrong place or should that have worked?

Comment: Is this happening only on IE or have you tested it on other browsers as well?

Comment: It's happening in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Comment: Working fine for me in FF and Chrome latest versions.

Comment: Are you talking about the jsFiddle? @BillyMoat

Comment: As I said in my original post it does work fine in the jsFiddle but the image shows what happens when I include that code into my site.

Comment: in your site, are you manipulating any other parents div tags. for instance toggling any element to display=none. because the piece of code you provided should work perfectly, unless there are other elements in your site that might be effecting the map we are not aware of

Comment: I'm using jQuery to toggle `.show()` and `.hide()` with the page being hide when the site is accessed.

Comment: @PrakashChennupati I tried setting the page to show and it works fine, but I need the page to be hidden until access. How can I go about this?

Comment: what do you mean by access? is it accessed by user initiated by say a click of button (show map)?

Comment: Yea the page should only show when a user clicks on `Contact Us` link.

Comment: I posted an answer below see if that works, you are initializing your google maps on page load but the div to display it is currently hidden so map does not render. you need to call your google map function inside the toggle `.show()` and `.hide()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Google maps initialization should be in a function, if it's not make sure it is. Then you can only initialize the map after you toggle it, this will also make sure it doesn't get loaded if the user doesn't wish to see it.

```
function init_maps(){

    // google maps api goes here

}

var init = false;

$('.contact_us').click(){

    if(!init){

        init_maps();
        init = true;
    }

    $('.contact_us').slideToggle();

}
```

Comment: I've placed the map code in the `init_maps()` function but I don't think I'm calling it correctly see below
  `$("#Contact").on("click", function (event) {
    $("#divs").removeClass('activeTab');
    $(this).addClass('activeTab');
    $("#ContactContent").show();
    $("#divs").hide();
    if (!init) {

      init_maps();
      init = true;
    }

    $('#mapContainer').slideToggle();
});`

Comment: Sorry ignore my ramblings in the past comment, I didn't copy the variable over. Thanks for the help!

Comment: no problem, your welcome. I had to deal with this same issue as well when i was working with the Google API :)